# Unnest one column list to many columns in tidyr

Tags: r, tidyr

For example, I have a tidy data frame like this:

```
df <- tibble(id=1:2,
         ctn=list(list(a="x",b=1),
                  list(a="y",b=2)))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
     id        ctn
  <int>     <list>
1     1 <list [2]>
2     2 <list [2]>
```

How could I unnest `ctn` column to the right so that the data frame will be like this:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
     id     a     b
  <int> <chr> <dbl>
1     1     x     1
2     2     y     2
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With `dplyr` and `purrr`

```
df %>% 
  mutate(ctn = map(ctn, as_tibble)) %>%
  unnest()
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 3
>      id     a     b
>   <int> <chr> <dbl>
> 1     1     x     1
> 2     2     y     2
> ```

Comment: use `as_tibble` instead of `as.data.frame` if you want to avoid the warning (which you otherwise might want to include as output). Or add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`

Comment: @docendodiscimus Thanks, made an edit. Completely forgot about `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`, changing it through `options()` on start.

Comment: note for others: this works for list-columns of lists, but doesn't for list-columns of vectors. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49889246/how-to-unnest-column-list for a list-column of lists solution

Answer (score 2):

One option is

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, unlist(ctn, recursive = FALSE), id]
#   id a b
#1:  1 x 1
#2:  2 y 2
```

---

Or with `tidyr`

```
library(tidyverse)
df$ctn %>%
     setNames(., df$id) %>%
     bind_rows(., .id = 'id')
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#   id     a     b
#  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#1     1     x     1
#2     2     y     2
```

Answer (score 0):

In a tidy way we can now (dplyr `1.0.2` and above) do this using `rowwise()`:

```r
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(as_tibble(ctn))
```

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Rowwise: 
     id ctn              a         b
  <int> <list>           <chr> <dbl>
1     1 <named list [2]> x         1
2     2 <named list [2]> y         2
```

And sticking to `purrr` we can also:

```r
df %>% mutate(map_dfr(ctn, as_tibble))
```

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
     id ctn              a         b
  <int> <list>           <chr> <dbl>
1     1 <named list [2]> x         1
2     2 <named list [2]> y         2
```